# Can anyone explaint the output?

Tags: java

I know the output is four one three two. Can any one explain how? Since there are five items, but only four are printed.

```
TreeSet map = new TreeSet();

map.add("one");
map.add("two");
map.add("three");
map.add("four");
map.add("one");
Iterator it = map.iterator();
while (it.hasNext() ) 
{
    System.out.print( it.next() + " " );
}
```

Comment: Side comment: calling a set `map` is quite misleading, call it `set` instead!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TreeSet does not allow duplicate entries.
When it is accessed it will return elements in natural order (alphabetical order).

Refer:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: (If you _don't_ want this behavior, maybe look at Guava's [`TreeMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html).)

Answer (score 1):

[Set's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) doesn't allow duplicates .Where you are adding duplicate again like 'one' it is not being added .

```
TreeSet map = new TreeSet();

    System.out.println(map.add("one"));
    map.add("two");
    map.add("three");
    map.add("four");
    System.out.println(map.add("one"));

    Iterator it = map.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext() )
    {
        System.out.print( it.next() + " " );
    }
```

**Result:**

```
true
false
```

Second element didn't get added to the set .

While adding it checks `if(e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))` is true then only add element to `Set` otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet is an Implementation of Set Interface

**And Set always contain only unique elements**

So even though you have put 5 elements the TreeSet actually contains only 4 since "one" is
repeated twice.